# How to detect if a site lets you upload files?

Tags: javascript, selenium, web-scraping, file-upload, web-crawler

I would like to be able to tell if a site lets you upload files. I can think of two main ways sites do it and ideally I'd like to be able to detect both:

- Button
- Drag & Drop

PhantomJS documentation has this example snippet:

```js
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.uploadFile('input[name=image]', '/path/to/some/photo.jpg');
```

but it's not clear how I could figure out that `input[name=image]` actually supports uploading.

Currently, my crawlers are following all links and buttons on sites but I am not sure how to detect that "a file upload pop-up has been opened". The D&D case is even less clear to me. I need a solution for a single page and obviously I can then go and apply it to every page I pass.

**UPDATE**
Turns out most of the time this does the trick:

```js
document.querySelector('input[type=file]').click()
```

However, D&D areas aren't always clickable and you can't always assume `[ondrop]` will be present. Sometimes, the drop listener is added in code:

```js
object.addEventListener("drop", myScript);
```

How can I check for presence of such elements then?

Comment: How about input[type=file] ?

Comment: What's your goal?

Comment: to identify cyberlocker sites on the internet, and that's a very strong feature

Comment: The answer is, you can't.  File uploads/downloads don't even have to occur with a UI.  So, I don't know what your requirements are specifically, but if you need any sort of reliability, you should re-evaluate what is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a form has **enctype="multipart/form-data"** or not. or search for input with **type=file** in html page.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the best approach to upload files with selenium is to send the file to be uploaded directly to element located by this CSS Selector `input[type=file]`.
So in order to check if some web page supports file uploading you can by checking if that page contains `input[type=file]` element.
This element is normally not visible and not interactable by GUI so you can only check it's existence, not visibility etc.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing can get you 100%, but i think 99% it works with `input[type=file]` unless user wasn't creating it at runtime using javascript.

Or you can check for form's enctype but also it isn't always works as there's a good chance that user compress and changes the file into base64, then there will be no need for enctype to be multipart/form-data.
So `input[type=file]` is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

So selecting the file input type works most of the time:

```
document.querySelector('input[type=file]')
```

Sometimes it catches the drag & drop fields too because it is still the same element, just with a different "setup".

Sophisticated setups that use an event on an arbitrary element and do the rest in js would still be missed. I'll update when I discover the right way of doing this.